# How can i trigger keyboard focus (tab key) event on an element in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios

I have a list of tabs and I basically want to automate a test case in `XCUITest` where I can navigate between tabs through tab key or right/left arrow keys in `iPhone / iPad`.

I had tried making the tabsView as my FirstResponder.

Code:

```
self.tabTitles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"TAB1", @"TAB2", @"TAB3", @"TAB4",@"TAB5", @"TAB6", @"TAB7", @"TAB8"]];

self.tabsView = [[AdobeSCTabs alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.tabsView.delegate = self;
[_tabsView becomeFirstResponder];
[self.testingView addSubview:self.tabsView];
```

But using this code, the control moves to the first tab item when i press tab key manually.

I had searched "KeyEvents" , but as Apple Documentation, they are for macOS.
I want to automate pressing a tab key on this entire list of tab items. So that when i call a method that would first press tab key on first item and then in the loop to the next tab items.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure an out-of-the-box solution for this exists. I implemented it as follows:

Create a subclass of `UITextField`:

```
class TextField: UITextField { ... }
```

In there, add a property:

```
@IBOutlet var nextTextField: TextField?
```

Then, inside your storyboard, or in code, hook up the text fields' `nextTextField` property & **make sure the delegates are set**.

Make your view controller conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement the method `shouldReturn`:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    (textField as? TextField)?.nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

You can now use the return key to get the desired behavior :)

---

<sup>Sorry for Swift code, I'm not firm in Objective-C</sup>